# SSL certificate chain incomplete on web.py

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, web.py

I can't work out how to correctly setup the SSL certificate chain on a web.py app...

In the python code I have:

```
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = "/path/mycert.pem"
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate_chain = "/path/mychain.ca-bundle"
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = "/path/mykey.key"
```

And when I visit the domain in Chrome it says it is Secure.

---

However,

- When I try to send webhooks from a Rails app it responds:

  ```
  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  ```
- If I try to connect using openssl at the command prompt like this:

  ```
  openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mydomain.com:443
  ```

  ..it only shows the domain's certificate, not the rest of the chain, and the output contains error messages:

  ```
  verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
  verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
  ```
- If I run the domain through [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html), although it passes with a B rating, under certificates it says:

  ```
  Chain issues    Incomplete
  ```

  ...and under Certification Paths the intermediates are marked as "Extra download" rather than "Sent by server"

---

I've tried some different combinations of file contents and file extensions.

E.g. I've tried putting:

- Only intermediate certificates;
- Intermediates and the root certificate;
- Domain, intermediates and root

...into the certificate_chain file. I've also tried including the whole chain in the certificate file. And I've tried extensions .crt, .pem, .perm, .ca-bundle

Does anyone have any suggestions for proper file format, inclusion method, file extension or any other config options I might need? Thanks!

---

P.S. Python version is 2.7.12
and pip freeze shows the following packages installed:

```
cffi==1.8.3
cryptography==1.5.2
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.1
ipaddress==1.0.17
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycparser==2.16
pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
requests==2.11.1
six==1.10.0
web.py==0.38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`web.py` v0.38 doesn't use certificate chains out-of-the-box. That means it ignores your `CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate_chain` edit, because it's not passed through.

Fortunately, there's an easy patch, per https://github.com/movb/webpy/commit/9f9f6838e49f17cf395282392c3fc2762a97460b

Edit `web/httpserver.py`, to pass through `ssl_certificate_chain` if defined. Then your code will work.

```
== web/httpserver.py ==
- def create_ssl_adapter(cert, key):
+ def create_ssl_adapter(cert, key, chain=None):

- adapter = pyOpenSSLAdapter(cert, key)
+ adapter = pyOpenSSLAdapter(cert, key, chain)

- server.ssl_adapter = crate_ssl_adapter(server.ssl_certificate, server.ssl_private_key)
+ server.ssl_adapter = create_ssl_adapter(server.ssl_certificate, server.ssl_private_key,
+                                         getattr(server, 'ssl_certificate_chain', None))
```